# Debugging through stacked dlls in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and I have an ASP solution which uses several compiled dlls that reference one another sequentially i.e. my solution references A.dll, A.dll uses B.dll and so on. My solution uses .NET 4.0 and the dlls have each been compiled in .NET 3.5. I want to debug the entire stack until a call in the last dll (D.dll). These are the dlls:

[image]

**What I did:** I've unchecked *Enable Just My Code* and I checked *Enable .NET Framework source stepping*. I generated the pdb files for each dll using dotpeek and then I moved them in Symbols Cache folder and also specified modules to load these specific dlls.

When I debug (I run the solution in Debug mode with Any CPU configuration) I can see each pdb loaded in the Debug/Windows/Modules window, I can see the source code for each window, and everything works ok until I reach A.dll. When I try to step into B.dll, I get the following message:

> Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing
>   that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native
>   runtine code is executing).

What is weird is that if I set Function Breakpoint in the D.dll, that breakpoint is hit, but the same approach does not work with B or C. There is no warning like 'The current breakpoint will not be hit', it just does not trigger. I want to see the entire flow from my solution to the last dll.

Does anybody have any idea why this happens? Do I need to do something else to cascade through the stack call?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would enable Native mode debugging, so I could see where it is stepping into.  I think you need to do that in your project settings.

Comment: @DaveTillman, With Native Mode enabled, when I step into that B.dll function it enters a class from D.dll (used in that B.dll function) and when it steps out of that, it enters the same break state.

Comment: I've had problems step-debugging between different versions of .NET. Do you have the option to upgrade your 3.5 stuff to 4.0 (even temporarily)?

Comment: @tgolisch, I don't have the original source code of those libraries, but I think dotPeek can decompile a dll into a project. I shall try and come back with the results.

Comment: I've managed to debug through the dll's finally after exporting into individual projects using dotpeek, removing and adding each reference between the projects. Likely there was something wrong with those references. Overall pretty nasty job as the decompiling produced lots of errors.

Comment: Nice work!  Do you want to post this as your answer. Then others can benefit from it (some people don't read un-answered questions).